# How to configure order in trigger parameterized build on other projects jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a  JOB {A} which is having **trigger parameterized build on other projects** in POST Build Actions 
I have set 2 Jobs {B} and {C}.
I wanna make configuration in such that 
First if A is Stable then trigger B and After trigger C. 
But i don not want to make C as a child to B.

Answer (score 2):

In JOB {A} you need waiting while JOB {B} running, when you run JOB {C}. For example:

JOB {A}

```
//do something
build job: "JOB {B}", quietPeriod: 0, wait: true 
//"quietPeriod: 0" without pause, "wait: true" waiting until downstrem job (JOB {B}) is finished
build job: "JOB {C}", quietPeriod: 0, wait: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper project using `MultiJob` plugin (MultiJob project). You can implement this logic there