# Can Jenkins pipeline builds use existing build jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to use an existing build job in Jenkins build pipelines?

Could somebody give me an example of how this would look like?

Comment: My example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40634829/6528221

Comment: @anton, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using the [`build`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) step.

```
build "jobname"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get more help on how to build a job/other syntax from the `Pipeline Syntax` link in the `Pipeline` section of that particular Pipeline

That link customizes your syntax according to the particular job you want to build, so that if you have any parameters in your job, you can add them easily in your command